# Air Filtering using a Air Tank

Tags: compressed-air

I just got a theory, However I don't know if it would work the way I wanted it to, though I still have hope and want to see if you agree with me.

As we all know, CO<sub>2</sub> Slowly sinks as it is heavier than air and oxygen.

My theory is to get a double valved tank (one valve on each end), use an air compressor to compress air into the tank, then let the CO<sub>2</sub> sink to the bottom, and slowly let the air out through the bottom valve.

This theory probably wont be as effective because you cant find X (the amount of CO<sub>2</sub> that was injected into the tank), but we know that there was CO<sub>2</sub> in the tank so some if not all was released.

I wanted to see if you guys agreed with my theory as I am just a High School Senior with no engineering experience just coming up with crazy theories.

Comment: A chemist can explain the exact mechanisms, but CO2 and O2 are too close in weight for this to make a practical difference unless you have a very very tall tank.

Comment: Would heating/cooling of the tank/gasses make a difference? I know I dont want to toy with heat too much near oxygen because thats a big no-no.

Comment: not unless you cool it to liquid

Comment: Start by looking up all the properties of the gasses you are considering, you may find you answer many of your own questions. Libraries have books with that sort of information - one I still use is Geick Technical Formulae as it has a lot of condensed information useful for engineers.

Comment: Ok, Thank you all for your help. Im just looking for a cheaper way to filter out air. Im looking to go paramotoring and need a safe way to have an emergency air cylinder for both high flying and incase i go into the water.

Comment: So where's all the CO2 coming from then?

Comment: CO2 may be more dense at typical temperatures, but gases will still mix. [See here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/213903/behavior-of-two-gases-in-a-closed-container)

Comment: Something being "heavier" or "lighter" than air doesn't make much difference inside a container.  By diffusion the gases will want to mix to a uniform distribution everywhere, even if you started with dry ice at the bottom of a tank of air.  So the reverse proces, starting with premixed gas, would certainly never unmix itself as you suggest.